# http authentication basic not working with parameters in uri

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I've an API, I am trying to do basic authentication to call it, the first call with this GET request :

```
https://example.com/test/api/v1/api
```

the brower send me the user and password. I can to connect, but if I call a second request with paramters like this :

```
https://example.com/test/api/v1/api/5
```

The browser send me again a modal to connect with user and password. At this moment I can't to connect, user and password not reconized...

In the .htaccess file I have :

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

The api.php file contain :

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Authentification canceled';
    exit;
} else {
    $login = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $pwd = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    if (isset($usersWS) && is_array($usersWS) && isset($usersWS[$login]) && $usersWS[$login] != "" && $usersWS[$login] == $pwd)
        //if ($login == "toto" && $pwd= "toto1234")
    {
        echo "connecte";
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Authentification incorrecte';
        exit;
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong ? The POST request works fine.

After few researches, I think it's my .htaccess file that wrong.

When I send this request :

```
https://example.com/test/api/v1/api.php?id=12
```

It's work fine ! But with this  request :

```
https://example.com/test/api/v1/api/5
```

Not working.

So, how I can define rules in .htaccess ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have more rewriting going on in your .htaccess? I don’t think using the `L` flag with the rule shown makes much sense.

Comment: You right, I delete the L and it's working fine now ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use PHP to do the Basic Auth for you, you can put all that in your `.htaccess` file. For that to work you'll have to generate the user/password combination and put them in a file on the server `/path/to/.htpasswd`, and then in your `.htaccess` file you can put this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Website Name"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Why I don't have to use the basics Auth? There is a reason ?

Comment: This method is still using Basic, but it’s doing it in the web server, one step before php